# Auth0 automatically logs in user on second time

Tags: android, auth0

For first time `Auth0` launches login screen just fine, but when i log out, and login again, it automatically logs in without showing the login screen.

If i remove chrome history then it seems to be working fine.

This is my code to login.

```
public void doLogin(Activity activity){

    WebAuthProvider.init(auth0)
            .withScheme("com.package.app")
            .withAudience(String.format("https://%s/api/",
                    AUTH0_DOMAIN))
            .withScope("openid profile email offline_access read:current_user update:current_user_metadata")
            .start(activity, webCallback);

}



private final AuthCallback webCallback = new AuthCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(@NonNull Credentials credentials) {
        credentialsManager.saveCredentials(credentials);
        accessToken= credentials.getAccessToken();
    }
```

When i press `logout button` i execute following code.

```
credentialsManager.clearCredentials();
```

This logs out the user, but it does not clear the session from chrome.

Is there any way i can clear the session from browser.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to Auth0 seamlessly logging you in after checking the user's SSO cookie exists and is therefore logged in (you will not be prompted for login credentials). This is because on logout you are not actually redirecting the user to the `/v2/logout` endpoint to clear this SSO cookie: https://auth0.com/docs/logout